# ZSH command not found, even if command is in my $PATH

Tags: bash, shell, path, zsh

So I have a script called `kc` which compiles Kotlin files into a jar.

The file is located at `~/Documents/KotlinPlayground/bin` and my $PATH looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/Documents/KotlinPlayground/bin:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
```

when I just type `kc SomeFilt.kt` into the command line I get a `zsh: command not found: kc`, but if I type in `~/Documents/KotlinPlayground/bin/kc SomeFile.kt` it works.

So how come zsh can't find my script even though its in the path?

---

Here is an image showing the problem:

[image]

---

I also tried adding `#!/bin/bash` to the top of `kc` and continued getting the same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that zsh is not interpreting `~/` correctly. You could replace `~/Documents` to `/home/user/Documents` to solve the problem.

Comment: Yep! thanks, I guess zsh doesn't like relative paths - making it an absolute path fixed the problem